# Ostream_iterator и пользовательский тип

Tags: c++, классы, шаблоны-с++

Доброго времени суток. Вопрос: как с помощью ostream_iterator вывести пользовательский тип?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>
using namespace std;

ostream& operator<<(ostream& output, const pair<int, int>& data)
{
    output<<data.first<<' '<<data.second;
    return output;
}

class CL
{
    pair<int, int> p;
    int count;
public:
    CL():p(4,5)
    {}
    void print() const
    {
        ostream_iterator<pair<int, int>> ostrIt(cout);
        *ostrIt=p;
    }
};

int main()
{
    CL cl;
    cl.print();
}
```

Есть перегруженный оператор << для pair со специализацией int и int, но почему-то его не находит. Заранее благодарен

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Не надо присваивать ostrIt . Вы же перегрузили operator<< а не operator= . Так почему же вы используете второй?
Да, ну и непонятно зачем вообще нужен ostrIt, можно же просто в std::cout выводить.

Ну и ещё совет, чаще используйте typedef (для pair<int,int> например) и не ленитесь, не пишите using std*

Comment: У ostream_iterator есть перегруженный operator=, который как раз принимает тип, для которого специализирован ostream_iterator<_Ty, _Elem, _Traits>& operator=(const _Ty& _Val). А в нем как раз и вызывается operator<< для этого типа. На самом деле я пытался массив выводить, просто чтобы много писанины не копировать, сократил пример до демонстрации ошибки

Comment: @Waylander123 ну там по-моему нет смысла так извращаться. Если есть ostream_iterator, то проще вызвать что-нибудь вроде std::copy и просто скопировать диапазон в него.

Comment: Andrey Buran, я именно так и делал, с помощью std::copy копировал весь вектор из пар int в ostream_iterator, и как раз такая ошибка и возникла

Answer (score 0):

В общем, все стало понятно. Так как ostream_iterator относится к пространству имен std и оба аргумента (ostream и pair) тоже к std, то поиск перегруженных функций производится только в std. Соответственно, можно этот оператор заключить в std, и все будет работать (только дурновато так делать, наверное). Другое решение - создать класс в global namespace, который будет содержать только открытый член pair, и перегружать << уже для него (так как теперь один из параметров в глобальном пространстве имен, то в нем теперь тоже будет идти поиск)